# How to count the frequency of a word >20

Tags: awk, text-formatting

Using exclusively AWK, I need to count the occurrence of a word only when greater than 20 characters. I've already found the way to count the frequency of a word, but I have some problems in setting this parameter.

In a second moment, I would like to sub these words with synonyms which I am going to define, but skipping one word.

I mean:
If "hello" has 30 occurrences, I would like to sub the `2nd`, `4th`, `6th` and so on with "hi", instead `1st`, `3rd`, ... are still "hello".

This is what I've done:

```
BEGIN { FS="[^a-zA-Z]+" } {
     for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
         word = tolower($i)
         words[word]++
     }
 }
 END {
     for (w in words)
          printf("%3d %s\n", words[w], w)
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix.SE! So that we can help you in the best possible way, it would be great if you could [edit] your question to show what you've already done in more detail.

Comment: On a line or in a file, because the latter is significantly more complicated.

Comment: In a small file!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
BEGIN { flag=0; FS="[^a-zA-Z]+" } {
     for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
         word = tolower($i)
         if ($0 ~ /hello/ ) {
             if (flag) {
                 sub ("hello", "hi", word );
             }
            flag= !flag
         }
         words[word]++
     }
 }
END {
        for (w in words)
           printf("%3d %s\n", words[w], w)
    }
```

What the above does is setting a `flag` to `0` in the initialization of the `awk` program.

Within the iteration of the file it checks for `hello` in the input string, if `hello` is found it checks the state of `flag`. If `flag` is `0`, do not change `hello` to `hi`.

Then toggle the value of `flag` (0 => 1, 1 => 0).

At the next `hello` occurence the `flag` value will be `1` and the substitution of `hello` to `hi` will be made.

Comment: You will need to either save every line or read the file twice as OP wants to change occurences after calculating the number.

Comment: Sure, too much focus on the replacement part that I forgot the frequency requirement :-)